# Paint Bucket not filling selection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a selection in Photoshop that looks like this:

[image]

When I Paint Bucket (or Edit-Fill), it comes out all wrong and fills half wrong and half too far:

[image]

What am I missing? How can I get it to fill the selection exactly? You can see my fill settings at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set a feather on your selection.

Go back to your selection marquee tool and make sure Feather is set to 0.